# ngx-select-dropdown set displayKey with multiple values

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdownbox, ngx-select-dropdown

I am using `ngx-select-dropdown` with search feature and I want to set multiple `displayKey` values like: `firstname` and `lastname`.

Below is my `config` object:

```
dropdownconfig = {
    displayKey: 'firstName, lastName',
    search: true,
    placeholder: 'Select User',
    height: '150px'
};
```

**html:**

```
<ngx-select-dropdown (change)="selecteAdmin($event)" [config]="dropdownconfig" [options]="allUserData" [(ngModel)]="singleSelect" [multiple]="false" ></ngx-select-dropdown>
```

How to display multiple values for `displayKey`? Also, need validation on that drop-down.

Comment: can you provided the template code as well ?

Comment: @Plochie added `html` code

Comment: So currently `allUserData` is array of string, correct?

Comment: @Plochie yes, correct!

Comment: I have a doubt, what do you mean by multiple values for `displayKey`? `displayKey` is used if your data is of complex type. So if your `allUserData` is `allUserData = [
    { firstName: 'val1'} ]`, then in dropdown you will see `val1`. Can you please elaborate more.

Comment: I want to display `firstNAme` and `lastNAme` @Plochie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom field in your array object. And use it as key.

```js
dropdownconfig = {
    displayKey: "custom",
    search: true,
    placeholder: "Select User",
    height: "150px"
  };


  allUserData = [
    { firstName: 'first1', lastName: 'last1'}, 
    { firstName: 'first2', lastName: 'last2'},
    { firstName: 'first3', lastName: 'last3'},
    { firstName: 'first4', lastName: 'last4'}
  ]

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let user of this.allUserData) {
      user['custom'] = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
    }
  }
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7ruab)

Answer (score 1):

Same question is open on the library. You can't do that. [Read it here](https://github.com/manishjanky/ngx-select-dropdown/issues/88). I have copied workaround below.

You can do with your custom property of array/ object.
For example :

- Let say you have Person (id, firastName, lastName, age) array/ object.
- Create new custom property as : name of Person object and set values as : `firstName + lastName`
- Use Person ( (id, firastName, lastName, name, age) array/object and dispayKey as : name

Achieve merging by adding new key. You can loop through array/object. For ex.

```
users.forEach((user) => {
    user.name = user.firstName + user.lastName;
});
```

Comment: Can you pls give me example with custom object?

Comment: I am not getting how to do that, it'll be helpful if you give example code.